# How to change JSON string to a single array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json string, now i want it to become another string like an array and the $key is the same with $value

original string:

```
$input='
{
        "label_values":[
        "OK1","OK2","OK3"
        ]
}'
```

tried json_decode

```
$obj = json_decode($input);
$results = $obj->{'label_values'};
$result = implode(",", $results);
```

and $result export OK1,OK2,OK3

$key is the same with $value,i want it change to below example

```
Array(
        "OK1"=>"OK1",
        "OK2"=>"OK2",
        "OK3"=>"OK3"
)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: can you `print_r($results);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `array_combine()`.

`array_combine()` returns an array using first argument as keys and second argument as values:

```
$result = array_combine( $results, $results );
```

<kbd>**[3v4l demo](https://3v4l.org/K73PI)**</kbd>

---

- See more about [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)